# Question about Istikhara?

Tags: istikharah

One of my friend wants to do Istikhara for marriage. But I know that he is not doing good deeds. All the time I mean all the year he talks to non-mehram friends even still he have a non-mehram friends and even he doesn't pray 5 times prayer all the year. His mother said him to do Istikhara even her mother also given him rights to make non-mehram friends. Can you please tell me now is it right to do Istikhara for one girl for marriage  when you already have so many non-mehram friends and you did so many wrong things?

What I actually mean is that people do wrong thing, every time when they commit a sins they don't even think about Allah, or what Allah wants? But when the times comes for marriage they started to do Istikhara. Is it right to do like this when all other things you are doing is haram?

Comment: Did you enter his heart and see what is in it? Do you know what he does behind closed doors when no one is watching?

Comment: So what you are saying is if a person commits sins then he has no right to turn to LORD and ask for favors? That's a bit strange way to put it, don't you think? Just because one person commits sins, doesn't mean they should stop doing all the good things they do and start doing the bad things. That's not how it is meant to be. Let people do whatever good they can do and if they do sins as well, let the goods that they do turn them away from their sins. In a hadith its mentioned that a man offered all his Salah but did other sins, it was said about him: let him be, his prayer will turn him away

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused of what you wrote, sometimes you seem to speak about a boy and sometimes you seem to speak about a girl.

Now any way: We know that Allah is all forgiving therefore you will find some ahadith (hadiths) which advise us never to judge people and never to say that this person would go to jannah or this one to hell. as Allah only knows what is in their hearts and maybe they where big sinners but at the end they made a sincere repentance and expiation and did good deeds and inchallah they might go to jannah. So you should avoid these kinds of thoughts and try to give your friend good advise like telling him to do sincere repentance and expiation... the rest is in the hand of Allah!

Allah says:

> - Do they not know that it is Allah who accepts repentance from His servants and receives charities and that it is Allah who is the
>     Accepting of repentance, the Merciful?
>
> [Surat at-Tawba (9:104)]
>
> - Except for those who repent, believe and do righteous work. For them Allah will replace their evil deeds with good. And ever is Allah
>     Forgiving and Merciful.
>
> [Surat al-Furqan (25:70)]
>
> - And it is He who accepts repentance from his servants and pardons misdeeds, and He knows what you do.
>
> [Surat ash-Shuraa(42:25)]

On the other hand we are all sinners and we all do bad things bad Allah still accepts our dua' and still says:

> And when My servants ask you, [O Muhammad], concerning Me - indeed I
>   am near. I respond to the invocation of the supplicant when he calls
>   upon Me. So let them respond to Me [by obedience] and believe in Me
>   that they may be [rightly] guided.
>
> [Surat al-Baqara (2:186)]

Doing istikhara is a known Sunna and it's a prayer followed by a dua' whether Allah accepts it from me you or your friend ... sincerely i could talk about myself: i don't know but i hope so!

Look at the Sahaba some of them have been promised to go to Paradise (jannah) but nonetheless in his fear of God (Allah) was afraid that any little or big mistake he did in his life would trow him into hell!

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score -1):

I think every people have a chance to be a better person. Only Allah can judge which is a good person and a bad person. We are humans; we cannot judge him. And, only Allah knows the sincerity of the dua. What we can do is just give him advice. What can we do is just following the rules of Allah and avoid the prohibition of Allah. This is the task of Allah, not us.